# Accessing Groups of LinkedLists Concurrently

Tags: java, concurrency

I have an array of LinkedLists (java.util.LinkedList) which I have to use. My goal is to be able to maximize speed, thus locking access to each linkedlist when in use, but allowing continued use and not locking the whole entire program

I know with Java's synchonized link list I could do something like this:

```
Queue[] linkedlistArray = new LinkedList[5]; //array of Linked Lists

//say I want to edit linklist 2, but want to allow other threads to access 
 the other linked lists 

int i = 2;
synchronized(linkedlistArray[i]){
   //edit this lift safetly
}
```

Is there a solution on how to do this with normal java linked lists. Perhaps I could keep an array of locks and lock the corresponding lock for each list? A little stuck with how to do this

Answer (score 0):

There are as many answers to this as there are... [insert appropriate analogy of own choice]

Are there both reads and writes? Relative frequency of those?

Is it even a problem? Measured? Expectations? What's the bottleneck?
A fun thought experiment?

A few options:

1. Use concurrent lock-free collections. see java.util.concurrent.
   Rarely write, often reads? Maybe use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`s or else maybe `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`. Have a look at docs for the [java.util.concurrent package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).
2. Just one big synchronize/lock and be happy.
3. One lock/synchronize per list as you suggest. Just use synchronize like in your code example. Or a separate object to synchronize on if you fancy or a `Lock` object.
4. Might be enough (not iterating through for example) to just use `Collections.synchronizedList(...)` for each of them when creating them.
5. As 2 but use a write and read lock (allow multiple concurrent readers but only one writer exclusively). See `ReadWriteLock`. Though be careful, it's rarely worth it "to do your own thing" in concurrency, other than learning of course.
6. As 3. but use readwrite locks as in 4 but do so per list.

I would definately go with a variant of 1 myself without knowing more and probably even so. Maybe 2 or 3. I've done 5 and 6 but rarely worth it, just for pleasure!

**Note:** `LinkedList` are rarely useful in practice, the author of the implementation hi,self said he never uses them. Just use `ArrayList`. Faster, less memory etc. unless doing lots of removals other than at the end.